# Mysql Query get free cars from table issue with flawed logic

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, innodb

I'm having some issues with understanding and avoiding a problem in one of my querys.

I am making an query where I try to select available cars in the selected time period- However I get an issue. If a car is rented it the period I select. in this case all my 3 cars is rented from: 2015-04-20 to 2015-04-25. The only other reservation is on Car 1, from 2015-04-26 to 2015-04-30. 
Issue appears when my query then returns Car1 as free in the timer period: 2015-04-20 to 2015-04-25, while actually still taken in another reservation.

The reason it returns car1, is that the reservation from 2015-04-26 to 2015-04-30 have car1 and it fulfills the requirements as it's not in the rent period.

My Current logic. A car is free to use if:

```
// Case 1: dropoff < r.pickup
// Case 2: pickup > r. dropoff
// Case 3: IF FK_CarID == Null
```

It's probably hard to understand from my text so here is an SQLfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13392/1
Theres the code for creation all the tables and my query.
And you can see that it returns 1 even though 1 is taken. So need to somehow make it forget 1 if 1 is already taken in that time period. Maybe by use of "between", but can't figure out how to stop it from returning other 1's, when it finds 1 is not an option.

Also here is an image of the table and query for overview purposes:
[Mysql Reservation Table and flawed Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItkPK.png)

For ease of use here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CarID FROM Cars c 
LEFT JOIN Reservations r ON (c.CarID = r.FK_car)
WHERE '2015-04-25' < r.pickUpDate 
OR r.FK_car IS NULL 
OR '2015-04-20' > r.dropOffDate;
```

And the creation of table Reservations and Cars:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
        carID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        model VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        make VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        creationYear INT(4) NOT NULL, 
        licenseNum VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL, 
        FK_station INT(6) UNSIGNED, 
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FK_station) 
            REFERENCES Stations(stationID) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE 
            ON DELETE SET NULL 
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Reservations (
        ReservationID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        pickUpDate DATE NOT NULL, 
        dropOffDate DATE NOT NULL, 
        FK_customer INT(6) UNSIGNED, 
        FK_car INT(6) UNSIGNED, 
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FK_customer) 
            REFERENCES Customers(customerID) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE 
            ON DELETE SET NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FK_car) 
            REFERENCES Cars(carID) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE 
            ON DELETE SET NULL 
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Hope you can help me fix my flawed logic. I'm pretty new to MySQL so getting into thinking in the correct way is still a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT distinct(car.carID) FROM Cars car
    where car.carId not in (
      select r.FK_car from Reservations r 
      WHERE (r.pickUpDate >= '2015-04-20' and r.pickUpDate <= '2015-04-25')
      and (r.dropOffDate >= '2015-04-20' and r.dropOffDate <= '2015-04-25')
      or (r.pickUpDate < '2015-04-20' and r.dropOffDate > '2015-04-25')
    )
```

Which is saying select cars which are **not** among reservations with:

- pickup and drop off dates are in the range
- pickup starts before range and ends after the range.

Comment: As I read this it would still give back car1 as a free car while it is not. Thats due to [reservation 4 in this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ItkPK.png) actually upholds the ranges. I need to somehow include that if it finds another reservation in between the two dates it should ignore all reservations with that carID

Comment: Maybe that can be done with two querys? Like first get all Id's thats between or equal to the dates and then in second query have WHERE not FK_car=id ?

Comment: Ok. I got the problem. Its easier to do with subselect

Comment: Ahh. thats clever. Just to make sure I get it.
You are effectively selecting all reservations that exist in the window of collision with the new reservation, and then choosing all other cars than those, as they must be free. Proven by elimination. 

never occurred to me you could look at it that way and have a select in a select. 

Thanks!! It works perfectly! :D

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help! I'm rather amazed how quick I could get help here :-)
Enjoy the rest of the weekend! :D

Answer (score 0):

We should get all the records where there is no reservation for the given range ...The subquery will first find all the cars which have reservations in the given period ... Then it will exclude those from the total cars we have ...   So we can proceed as below:

```
 Select distinct fk_car from Reservations where fk_car not in
(
Select fk_car from Reservations
where pickupdate<='2015-04-20' and dropoffdate>='2015-04-25'
);
```

Comment: yeah. Jonasnas was quicker with an update of his answer. But you are 100% correct. This is the way to do it. In my case you need some more where clauses, but the method is definitely the way to go. Thanks! :)